# c# assignment performance with different ways

Tags: c#, performance

everyone,recently i was debugging a program for improve performance.i notice a interest thing about assignment's performance.the below code is my test code.

CODE A

```
public class Word{....}

public class Chunk
{
    private Word[] _items;
    private int _size;
    public Chunk()
    {
        _items = new Word[3];
    }

    public void Add(Word word)
    {
        _items[_size++] = word;
    }
}
```

main

```
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            chunk.Add(new Word() { });//
        }
```

CODE B

```
public class Chunk
{
    private Word[] _items;
    private int _size;
    public Chunk()
    {
        _items = new Word[3];
    }

    public Word[] Words
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
    }

    public int Size
    {
        get{return _size;}
        set{_size=value;}
    }
}
```

main

```
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            chunk.Words[i] = new Word() { };
            chunk.Size + = 1;
        }
```

in my test with visual studio'profiling tool,calling the main method 32000 times,that performance shows the CODE B FASTER than the CODE A.why the CODE B faster than the CODE A?who can give me a suggestion?
thanks

update:sorry,i forgot increase _size code in the CODE B,i have updated my CODE B

update:  @Shiv Kuma Yes, code A is similar with Code B in the situation of 30000 call times. I tested the 700K file and the code can be called 29000 times or so.
Meanwhile, code B is 100 millisecond faster than Code A, and actually Code B is much better during the real segment. 
Here one more thing I’m wondering is why Code B is faster than Code A even for the same assignment? 
Anyway, thanks for you reply.

Comment: How much difference is there? And can you show us the code you're using to profile? If you're calling Code A and then Code B, try swapping it such that you call Code B and then Code A. Showing us how you're profiling this is important because there are many things that can be wrong in your profiling code.

Comment: I justed tested this out and there is almost no difference between the two you're talking 1 millisecond (some times and in favor of either of the methods) over 30,000 iterations. Unless you're seeing otherwise, this is a total waste of everyone's time.

Comment: accept an answer or leave comment or edit your question on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three reason I can think of.

1. Chunk.Add() is a method call, a method call is always expensive compared to same code running inline.
2. There are two incremnets in the first code sample ( _size++ and i++ )
3. chunk.Words array might cached locally (2nd example) therefore no need to evaluate chunk.items (1st example) every time Add is called.

Answer (score 1):

In CODE A you are incrementing twice. Once in your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

And once in your method:

```
_items[_size++] = word;
```

In CODE B you are only incrementing once in the for loop.

It isn't much but it would definitely cause the performance difference.

Yes, the method call would also add a small amount of overhead.

Comment: Plus the actual calling of the method in A vs. not calling a method in B is likely to be adding a small amount of overhead.

Comment: hi,dubmun,i forgot CODE B a code in the main loop.i have upated my code.

Comment: I edited my response but knightpfhor is right, the method call makes has a small impact as well. In the other example you are using only properties and they have about the same impact to performance as accessing your variables directly unless there is logic embedded in them.

Comment: In CODE B, Apart from i++ in for loop, there is "chunk.Size + = 1;" which is second instance increment.

Comment: Yes nils_gate. The original code did not include that line, it was edited after my original answer.